# Google Analytics - "gtm-msr" shows up as a top page/screen in GA4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Ok Google Analytics peeps - need help to remove something that shows up GA4 but not Universal Analytics and inflates our page/screens data and number.

When I view Page and screens in Google Analytics 4, gtm-msr comes up as one of our top 5 pages with a lot of traffic. In Universal Analytics, this never has shown up in pages. (In a month traffic, will show up as 2850 pageviews, 132 users, average engagement of 1.5 minutes, 10,000 event count.)

We have one tag setup to fire on all pages for the FB pixel.The tag for the Facebook pixel in Google Tag Manager was setup a long time with our properties, so this has not been changed or updated.

Any idea of how to remove this?

Anyone else see this in GA4 only?

Thanks!